# Exclude cells which aren't displayed with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I not able to exclude the cells which aren't displayed in my table.The following script allows to display the values which are not in the ComputerName column and if the cells match the values aren't displayed in the result.

the script:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = @($csv.ComputerName)
foreach ($row in $csv) {
  foreach ($col in 'OtherComputerName', 'OtherComputer', 'AndAgain') {
    if ($ref -contains $row.$col) { $row.$col = '' }
  }
}


$csv | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ComputerName |Format-Table -auto
```

the file:

```
ComputerName    OtherComputerName   OtherComputer   AndAgain
infra-1         infra-852           infra-2         infra-99
infra-98        infra-85            infra-44        infra-23
infra-5         infra-8             infra-1         infra-10
infra-2         infra-55            infra-8         infra-70
infra-62        infra-5             infra-852       infra-5
```

the result:

```
OtherComputerName OtherComputer AndAgain
----------------- ------------- --------
infra-852                       infra-99
infra-85          infra-44      infra-23
infra-8                         infra-10
infra-55          infra-8       infra-70
                  infra-852
```

I would like to exclude the empty cells but I don't know if the values are present but they are not displayed, can someone help me pls ?

expected result:

```
OtherComputerName OtherComputer AndAgain
----------------- ------------- --------
infra-852           infra-44     infra-99
infra-85            infra-8      infra-23
infra-8             infra-852    infra-10
infra-55                         infra-70
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean _"exclude the empty cells"_? Either you exclude the whole column, or you exclude the row from the result. The values are being replaced by your code: `$row.$col = ''`

Comment: The expected result is up

Comment: You need to provide a detailed explanation of the criteria you are using to get from the input data to the expected result. Just saying "exclude the empty cells" doesn't make sense, as your expected result has an empty cell in the middle column.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: v1.0 PowerShell ISE

Comment: Because this is not my question or answer, I will not be notified unless you tag me using `@gm...`. What is the result of `$PSVersionTable`? It's likely to be `2.0.x`, `4.0.x` or `5.0.x`. All use Engine version 1.

Comment: It is PSVersion 5.1

Answer (score 1):

What you want is possible, but I would not recommend it. In your code, you have *rows* and *columns*. The idea is that data along a row is related.

In your data, you are after several distinct columns where the **data along a row is not related**. So essentially you are after 3 distinct lists, not a table.

I would recommend creating distinct lists of your results. There are many ways to do this; I have done it by creating a variable that has the name of the column header.

Afterwards, you can manually display the values as a table if you would like.

**Input - test1.csv**

```
ComputerName;OtherComputerName;OtherComputer;AndAgain
infra-1;infra-852;infra-2;infra-99
infra-98;infra-85;infra-44;infra-23
infra-5;infra-8;infra-1;infra-10
infra-2;infra-55;infra-8;infra-70
infra-62;infra-5;infra-852;infra-5
```

**Code:**

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = @($csv.ComputerName)

# get csv headers; exclude computername
$myheaders = ($csv | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" -and $_.Name -ne "ComputerName"}).Name


$j = 0 # a counter

foreach ($col in $myheaders){

    # create a new variable that has the name of the column, and the value
    # that you are after (in column but not in $ref)
    New-Variable -Name $col -Value ($csv.$col | Where-Object {$_ -notin $ref})

    $k++
    if($k -gt $j){$j++} # get the longest column

}

# output formatted text, with left justified test that is 20 characters long.
# 0,1 and 2 are indexes that refer to the values after -f

"{0,-20}{1,-20}{2,-20}" -f "OtherComputerName","OtherComputer","AndAgain"
foreach($i in 0..$j){
    "{0,-20}{1,-20}{2,-20}" -f $OtherComputerName[$i],$OtherComputer[$i],$AndAgain[$i]
}
```

**Output:**

```
OtherComputerName   OtherComputer       AndAgain
infra-852           infra-44            infra-99
infra-85            infra-8             infra-23
infra-8             infra-852           infra-10
infra-55                                infra-70
```

Comment: I have an error : indexation impossible in a table Null

Comment: @charlo I've changed the top line `$csv = ...` to match your code. Other than that don't know why you'd be getting an error; I tested this on your data.

Comment: I know but the error provide at this line`"{0,-20}{1,-20}{2,-20}" -f $OtherComputerName[$i],$OtherComputer[$i],$AndAgain[$i]`

Comment: @charlo Are you using an input with different column headers?

Comment: No, I just copied your code to check and changed the filename if it was the problem, i didn't touch content of the file.

Comment: @charlo added input to my answer, and upgraded from `5.0` to `5.1` to test  on the same version; still working. Perhaps someone else on SO can provide answer that works for you.