# Read then display values in columns with a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

The current script :

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = @($csv.Column1)
foreach ($row in $csv) {
  foreach ($col in 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4') {
    if ($ref -contains $row.$col) { $row.$col = '' }
  }
}

$csv | Select-Object Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
```

The current result:

```
Column1  Column2   Column3   Column4
-------  -------   -------   -------
infra-1  infra-852           infra-99
infra-98 infra-85  infra-44  infra-23
infra-5  infra-8             infra-10
infra-2  infra-55  infra-8   infra-70
infra-62           infra-852
```

CSV File:

```
Column1    Column2      Column3     Column4
infra-1    infra-852    infra-2     infra-99
infra-98   infra-85     infra-44    infra-23
infra-5    infra-8      infra-1     infra-10
infra-2    infra-55     infra-8     infra-70
infra-62   infra-5      infra-852   infra-5
```

## This is what I want, example with Column1 as reference

## Then Column2 in the same output

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4
-------   -------   -------   -------
infra-98 infra-852 infra-44  infra-99
infra-62 infra-85  infra-8   infra-23
         infra-8   infra-852 infra-10
         infra-55            infra-70
                          
 
Column1   Column2    Column3    Column4
-------   -------    -------    -------
infra-1   infra-85   infra-2     infra-99
infra-98  infra-55   infra-44    infra-23
infra-2              infra-1     infra-10
infra-62                         infra-70
```

To be short I want to have four columns with only the cells not matching with the reference column. The values of the column reference must diseppear with the values that match with it. This question is about making many arrays the other question is about just about excluding the empty cells.

Comment: Your demand from the latter complex sentence is a bit incomprehensible (for me). Please [edit] the question and provide desired output satisfying rules of [mcve]. Maybe [Add Column to CSV Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17022017/3439404) could help?

Comment: I try to be, sry.

Comment: Your question is even less comprehensible now. Your last output sample is just your first output sample (that you said you don't want) times two. Please update your question with an example of the output you actually want.

Comment: I think it's the best I can do here.

Comment: If I try with another foreach it remove the Column1.

Comment: What you want is going to really complex, because you aren't treating your csv like a PowerShell object. With `Import-CSV` each line of the CSV is an individual object with properties of each header. In your question, each column is an array. What you want is doable, but would be complex because that's not how psobjects work.

Comment: Is it possible to get this result by another way ? I can also make it with a XLSX if needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude cells which aren't displayed with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647166/exclude-cells-which-arent-displayed-with-powershell)

Comment: This is differrent I wanted exclude the empty cells in the table here i want to get many table in the ouput